# How to get commit from specific branch using pydriller?

Tags: python, git

I am trying to try extracting data from github using pydriller.
I am using pydriller repo as an example.I can extract all the commits from master but when I add `only_in_branch` argument to extract other branch it gives error like this.

```
for commit in RepositoryMining(path_to_repo=path,only_in_branch="pydriller2").traverse_commits():
  File "C:\Users\cansa\Desktop\gamehunteralfa\venv\lib\site-packages\pydriller\repository_mining.py", line 220, in traverse_commits
    for commit in git_repo.get_list_commits(rev, **kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\cansa\Desktop\gamehunteralfa\venv\lib\site-packages\pydriller\git_repository.py", line 114, in get_list_commits
    for commit in self.repo.iter_commits(rev=rev, **kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\cansa\Desktop\gamehunteralfa\venv\lib\site-packages\git\objects\commit.py", line 277, in _iter_from_process_or_stream
    finalize_process(proc_or_stream)
  File "C:\Users\cansa\Desktop\gamehunteralfa\venv\lib\site-packages\git\util.py", line 329, in finalize_process
    proc.wait(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cansa\Desktop\gamehunteralfa\venv\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 408, in wait
    raise GitCommandError(self.args, status, errstr)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git rev-list --reverse pydriller2 --
  stderr: 'fatal: bad revision 'pydriller2'
'
```

There are two branches master and pydriller2 but ı cannot extract commits from pydriller2.

```
for commit in RepositoryMining(path_to_repo=path,only_in_branch="pydriller2").traverse_commits():
        print(str(commit.hash)+" "+str(commit.branches))
```

Can you help me with this problem please?

Comment: Your question lacks a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you missing `origin`, change to `only_in_branch='origin/pydriller2'`

[image]